# Filtrar SearchPanes [DataTables]

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, datatables, datatable

Tengo implementado un `SearchPanes` en mi proyecto y funciona sin problemas, pero deseo que al momento de filtrar el `SearchPanes` se actualice y se filtre también. Por ejemplo, este es mi `SearchPanes`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea es que, si selecciono, por ejemplo, a Daniel Fonseca (el primer empleado) los registros de la Fecha, Hora y Servicio se actualicen automáticamente a solo lo que coincida con Daniel Fonseca.

Actualmente si selecciono cualquier empleado todos los demás criterios de búsqueda quedan igual, entonces si selecciono a Daniel Fonseca y Enero 09/2021 no muestra ningún resultado porque no hay registros que coincida con esos criterios de búsqueda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No sé cómo hacer esto con la herramienta `DataTables`, ¿es posible hacer esto? y ¿cómo puedo hacerlo?

Answer (score 0):

Después de investigar más fondo me di cuenta que la solución es bien sencilla, solo se debe usar `searchPanes.cascadePanes` como se observa en el [siguiente ejemplo](https://datatables.net/extensions/searchpanes/examples/initialisation/cascadePanes.html).